# How to make sequelize model seperate file but same sequelize connection

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

everyone. I'm very new for sequelize ORM with nodejs.
I've just created couple files for models seperately and I also seperate sequelize.js to connect to database.

The problem is when I make association between model(file)(Self Associate work well) and I've got an error
**** "hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model"

I tried to solved this but doesn't work until I put every model in the same file. So, **I realized that every model must use common sequelize connection.**

Is there anyways to solve this problem without sequelize-cli (I don't want to use sequelize-cli)
My code belows

Many thanks,

sequelize.js

```
const config = require("config");
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.get("database"),
  config.get("user"),
  config.get("cipher"),
  {
    dialect: "mariadb",
    timezone: "Asia/Bangkok",
  }
);

module.exports = sequelize;
```

user.js

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("./sequelize");
const Position = require("./position");

class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
    imgurl: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    passphase: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "User",
    tableName: "users",
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

User.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: "CreatedUser",
  foreignKey: "user_id",
  through: "UserCreator",
});
User.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: "Creator",
  foreignKey: "creator_id",
  through: "UserCreator",
});

User.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: "ModifiedUser",
  foreignKey: "user_id",
  through: "UserModifier",
});
User.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: "Modifier",
  foreignKey: "modifier_id",
  through: "UserModifier",
});

User.belongsTo(Position);

module.exports = User;
```

position.js

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("./sequelize");
const User = require("./user");

class Position extends Model {}

Position.init(
  {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Position",
    tableName: "postions",
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

Position.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: {
    type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

module.exports = Position;
```

Comment: Where is the `sequelize.authenticate()` code?

Comment: It's in the other file.

Answer (score 2):

Sequelize has a `.define()` method to create all your schemas in JSON. If you want to keep your connection to the database separate from your models, I suggest doing something like this

./models/schemas/User.js

```
const userSchema = {
  attribute1: {
    type: ...,
    option1: ...,
    option2: ...,
    .
    .
  },
  .
  .
}

export default userSchema
```

Do the same with `Position.js`

Then:

./models/models.js

```
import {sequelize} from 'path/to/sequelize.js'
import positionSchema from './schemas/Position.js'
import userSchema from './schemas/User.js'


const User = sequelize.define("user", userSchema, { freezeTableName: true });
const Position = sequelize.define("position", positionSchema, { freezeTableName: true });


// add associations

export {
  User,
  Position,
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: So are `User` and `Position` connection-independent models now? If yes, how can I obtain a connection-specific one?

Comment: User and Position are defined independently if you want to modularize your code (which makes it easier to make edits later on). In order to connect two models, Sequelize allows you to create ‘associations’. 

See: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html

Comment: I meant: if you would like to find a user, you can `User.findOne`, but how could you tell to the code,that please use this model (`User`) and this sequelize connection (`sequelize`).